# Upsource & JIRA OnDemand / Cloud

Tags: rest, cors, jira, upsource

We are using JIRA cloud and apparently it's got the Remote API and is CORS configured.

However, with new project creation in Upsource...
Testing the JIRA link reports: "Connection failed" - I've checked the Upsource logs and there doesn't seem to be anything new reported in them.

Has anyone have success with Upsource and JIRA OnDemand?

It seems that JIRA OnDemand / Cloud doesn't allow CORS whitelisting: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-30371

Can anyone confirm that this is accurate?

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue in the [previous versions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/2.0/issue_tracker_integration.html) of Upsource. In 3.5, [server authentication](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/UP-6866) was implemented and since then CORS is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is not accurate. CORS is needed only for testing purposes (empirically speaking), however, once you create a project and provide credentials, upsource will simply use those to create issues / pull data / etc without any problems. At least this is the case for us.